# CSV to JSON in NodeJs with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, csv

My CSV file looks like:

```
"Some Comment here"
<Blank Cell> Header1 Header2
Header3      Value1   Value2
Header4      Value3   Value4
```

I want it to get converted into JSON and store in MongoDB as:

```
Obj: { Key1: Header1/Header2, Key2: Header3/Header4, Value: Value1/2/3/4 }
```

So basically, I am downloading the CSV file over HTTP and want to save the data in MongoDB in the said format.

I tried out many parser for last 2 days and unable to get it done. I am missing the basics of file/data parsing in Nodejs. Could you please help me in getting my basics right here?

It would be great if I could get the hang of character by character reading and changing this as per wish.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am finally able to get this working without using any parser. For newbie like me, it is best recommended to avoid the parser while we are learning.

I used String.split("\n") to slice the csv file line wise. Further, I used String.split(",") to further get each item in individual array item.

and finally, looped around the array to get my desired object and pushed it to mongo.

Cheers!